# Let $x^4-4x^3+mx^2+nx+1=0$ have four real roots. Then, what is $n,m$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $$x^4-4x^3+mx^2+nx+1=0$$ have four roots positive real number. Then : what is $n,m \in \Bbb R$

My try

Let four roots be $x=a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R^+$ so, $$x^4-4x^3+mx^2+nx+1=0\\(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=0$$ 
Next?

Comment: You just need to multiple them and then solve for coefficients.

Comment: It means the derivative has three and so on.

Comment: @A---B. Yeah   .answer=root

Comment: Are $a,b,c,d$ pairwise different?

Comment: Also are $a,b,c,d$ all real?Or can they be complex?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $4$ always has $4$ complex roots, some of which may be repeated.  Do you want $4$ *distinct* roots? Do you want $4$ *real* roots? Or *rational* roots? And do you want $m$ and $n$ to be real, integers, or what?

Comment: @BarryCipra. Real roots .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is $(m,n) = (6,-4)$.

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_4$ be the four roots of the polynomial
$$x^4 - 4x^3 + mx^2 + nx + 1 = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)$$
Let $\sigma_1, \ldots,\sigma_4$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials associated to $a_1, \ldots, a_4$.
$$
\sigma_1 = \sum_{i=1}^4 a_i,\quad
\sigma_2 = \sum_{1\le i < j \le 4} a_ia_j,\quad
\sigma_3 = \sum_{1\le i \le j \le k \le 4} a_ia_ja_k\quad\text{and}\quad
\sigma_4 = \prod_{i=1}^4 a_i
$$
If all $a_i$ is positive, it is clear all these $\sigma_k > 0$.

By [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), we have
$m = \sigma_2 > 0$ and $n = -\sigma_3 < 0$.

Let $S_0 = 1$ and $\displaystyle\;S_k = \frac{\sigma_k}{\binom{4}{k}}$ for $k > 0$. When all the roots are real, [Newton inequalitites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities) tell us

$$S_{k-1}S_{k+1} \le S_k^2\quad\text{ for } k = 1, 2, 3$$

For the polynomial at hand, we have
$(S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4) = \left(1, 1, \frac{m}{6}, -\frac{n}{4}, 1 \right)$.
This leads to $$
\frac{m}{6}  \le 1,\quad
-\frac{n}{4} \le \left(\frac{m}{6}\right)^2\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{m}{6} \le \left(-\frac{n}{4}\right)^2\tag{*1}$$

Since $-\frac{n}{4} > 0$, we can combine the last two inequalities to get
$$\frac{m}{6} \le \left(-\frac{n}{4}\right)^2 \le \left(\frac{m}{6}\right)^4\tag{*2}$$
Using the fact $m > 0$ and the first inequality in $(*1)$, we find $\displaystyle\;\frac{m}{6} = 1$.
Substitute this back into $(*2)$, we get $\displaystyle\;-\frac{n}{4} = 1$.

When $(m,n) = (6,-4)$, the polynomial
$x^4 - 4x^3 + mx^2 + nx + 1$ becomes $(x-1)^4$.
Counting multiplicity, it does have four positive real roots (all $a_k = 1$).

Answer (score 1):

**hint by Rolle**

$$f'(x)=4x^3-12x^2+2mx+n $$
has 3 roots then

$$f''(x)=12x^2-24x+2m $$

has 2 roots. So $\delta'=144-24m>0$.

or $m <6$.

Comment: Now what is $n,m$?

Comment: No roots positive real number

Comment: This is not the solution. For example, $m=-2, n =4$ satisfies your conditions $m<6$ and $n=2−m$, and it gives $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x + 1$ which has roots at $x = -1$ and $x = +1$. This contradicts the root condition.

Answer (score 0):

A geometric interpretation leads to the solution.

Write $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 + mx^2 + nx + 1 = (x-1)^4 - [(6-m)x^2 - (4+n) x]$.

So the roots $f(x) = 0$ are attained at the intersections of two functions
$g(x) = (x-1)^4 $ and $h(x) = (6-m)x^2 - (4+n) x$. From Salahamam_ Fatima's analysis it is already clear that $6-m \geq 0$. So let's rename  $a = 6-m$ and $b = -4-n$ and write $h(x) = a x^2  + bx$ with the only condition $a\geq 0$.

Obviously $h(x)$ is a parabola or a line, passing through the origin. So for $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, $h(x)$ can only intersect with $g(x) = (x-1)^4 $ at at most two points   with $x>0$, which are then roots of multiplicity $1$ of $f(x)$. (Also, there could be one tangential intersection which then would correspond to a root of $f(x)$ of multiplicity $2$.) (There can be more intersections with $x<0$). The figure illustrates this, plotting $g(x) = (x-1)^4 $ and, exemplarily, $h(x) = 2 x^2 + 4 x$, for $x>0$. 
[image: Intersections of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ for $x>0$.]

So this will not lead to solutions with four positive real roots of $f(x)$.

The only possibility to have an intersection at $x>0$ , representing a multiple root of $f(x)$, is to have $a = b =0$ which is $h(x) = 0$ which leads to only one  intersection $(x=1, y=0)$, so $x=1$ is a  root of $f(x)$ which is then fourfold.

Hence from $a = b =0$, we have $m=6$ and $n = -4$.